# stdin not working in shell while creating password of newuser

Tags: shell, sh

This is what i am doing but getting error .

Ask for username

```
read -p  "Enter your username to create: " USER_NAME

#Ask for real name

read -p "Enter your real name of account user: " REAL_NAME

#Ask for password

read -p "Enter your password for account:" PASSWORD

#Create User

useradd -c "${REAL_NAME}" -m  ${USER_NAME}

#Set password for user

echo ${PASSWORD} | passwd --stdin ${USER_NAME}

#Prompt user to change password

passwd -e ${USER_NAME}
```

The error that i am getting is below

> Error -
>
> passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin' Usage: passwd [options] [LOGIN]

Comment: The `passwd` program doesn't think it knows about an option `--stdin` — so why do you think it should?  Maybe you can try `passwd --help` to see what it recognizes as options.  In general, the `passwd` program reads from the terminal, not from standard input.  The variant you use may have alternatives, but reading the manual page for the program will reveal all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ohhh its working now thanks

Comment: If `chpasswd` exists on your system, it is designed for reading from stdin.